# Is there any way to check if a iPhone video file has been trimmed via metadata?

Tags: video, iphone

I am analyzing a `.mov` video recorded using an iPhone with ExifTool in macOS. It was recorded using the internal camera app on an iPhone. I have looked at the metadata of this file, but cannot figure out how to determine if the video has been trimmed—in length—on the iPhone.

If the person trimmed the video in length, it would have been done using the internal camera app which is the app the video was recorded on. So is possible to tell if the video has been clipped somehow via metadata?

I am using macOS High Sierra. I have access to Windows 7,10, and Ubuntu, as well.

Comment: I am using macOS High Sierra. I have access to Windows 7,10, and Ubuntu, as well. I checked the metadata using exiftool from the terminal for macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a decent question. And I have experimented on my iPhone 8 running iOS 11.2.1 and my Mac Mini (2012) running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.

I took a 4 second clip and trimmed it down. iOS will create a new “trimmed” file on the system which is different than what happens in iOS when images are edited; an edited image seems to be purely adjusted via metadata whereas a trimmed video becomes a new derivative clip.

I exported both videos as unmodified original videos and this is what I learned: My source video is named `IMG_3233.MOV` but the trimmed clip is then named `8AC05E42-5BBD-47B1-9A8B-F04C3A4FC787.TRIM.MOV`; note the `.TRIM.MOV` appended. Checking metadata with ExifTool 10.55 shows no obvious indications of the video being trimmed since it’s a new clip. The only outward indication that the clip is a trimmed derivative clip is from the `.TRIM.MOV` appended to the end of the filename.

So the answer is pretty much… No, there is no way currently to determine if a video clip made in iOS is trimmed via metadata. If the only indication is the filename it takes 2 seconds of effort to change that and “erase” any sign that the clip is indeed a trimmed derivative.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. The video I'm analyzing was made before iOS11 came out. I believe the device was using iOS10 then. Any clue if iOS10 does the same? I have an iPhone 7, but I've already upgraded to 11.